# Index into time series using another time series's index

Tags: pandas

I have two time series, one for minute stock data, and another for daily stock data. Is there some way I can index into my daily time series using the index from my minute time series?

```
daily_ts.head()

open    high    low close   volume
datetime                    
2019-04-23 05:00:00 260.15  265.60  255.75  263.90  10943859
2019-04-24 05:00:00 263.85  265.32  258.00  258.66  10727454
2019-04-25 05:00:00 255.00  259.00  246.07  247.63  21849393
2019-04-26 05:00:00 246.50  246.68  231.13  235.14  22360709
2019-04-29 05:00:00 235.86  243.98  232.17  241.47  16714476


minute_ts.tail()

open    high    low close   volume
datetime                    
2020-04-23 19:55:00 704.23  704.9000    703.3900    703.8200    34299
2020-04-23 19:56:00 703.81  704.9600    703.2201    703.2201    34028
2020-04-23 19:57:00 703.38  704.3799    703.3000    704.2100    40345
2020-04-23 19:58:00 704.48  705.2700    704.0701    704.6600    45458
2020-04-23 19:59:00 704.59  705.7200    704.0000    705.6300    64355
```

I'm trying to something along the lines of:

`minute_ts['prev_day_close'] = daily_ts[minute_ts.index]['close']`

I think should work except my minute_ts index isn't a string and I can't find any way to convert it for this use case.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `reindex` for the `daily_ts` as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
daily_ts = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": pd.date_range("2019-04-23", freq="D", periods=6),
                         "close": np.random.randint(100,150,6)})

minute_ts = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": pd.date_range("2019-04-23 23:57:00", freq="min", periods=6),
                         "close": np.random.randint(100,150,6)})
daily_ts = daily_ts.set_index("datetime")
minute_ts = minute_ts.set_index("datetime")
minute_ts["prev_day_close"] = daily_ts.close.reindex(minute_ts.index, method='ffill')
```

And the result for `minute_ts` is:

```
                   close  prev_day_close
datetime                                  
2019-04-23 23:57:00    119             145
2019-04-23 23:58:00    142             145
2019-04-23 23:59:00    122             145
2019-04-24 00:00:00    133             102
2019-04-24 00:01:00    132             102
2019-04-24 00:02:00    149             102
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I spent a few hours trying to figure this out - your help is much appreciated. :)